# How to start portable pdflatex

Tags: kubuntu, latex, portable

I know that this is a very easy question. I have never used Linux before and I could not figure out how this has to be done.

I am installing a protable `texlive` on my Kubuntu machine. Now I want to run `pdflatex`. In the `texlive/bin/linux-i386/` directory there is the `pdflatex` file. If I use the `dir` command I can see that the file exists.

I tried to call `/path/to/texlive/bin/linux-i386/pdflatex test.tex` in the terminal but I get the error `.../pdflatex: File or directory not found`.

Calling `pdflatex test.tex` I get `This application is not installed. You can install it...`

Also using `sudo pdflatex` does not work.

How do I start it? Thanks for your help.

**Note**: The installation **has** to be portable. There is no way to use a not portable version.

Comment: If I run `/path/to/texlive/bin/linux-i386/pdflatex --version` I get the first error again: `.../pdflatex: File or directory not found`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution. It was only about me and my missing knowledge about Linux, LaTex and searching for the wrong terms on google. Sorry for the question.

I changed the path `path/to/texlive/bin/`**`linux-i386`**`/pdflatex` to `path/to/texlive/bin/`**`x86_64-linux`**`/pdflatex`. Now everything works fine.

Thank you for helping.